# Perl eval limits the size of block?

Tags: perl, eval

I have a simple Perl program which just concatenates a string read from file to a prefix 'qr'

```
  my $regex = eval 'qr'.$line;   
  my $myLength = length($regex);
  print "Length of string: $myLength\n";
```

With the size of `$line` is quite big (~100000 characters). It seems like `eval` just refuses to work. What i got for `$myLength` is just 0 while I still can print `$line`. Do you have any suggestion for that issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Check `$@`. If `$line` does not start and end with some decent delimiters, your expression will have an error.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the delimiters from `$line` and then create a regex object via interpolation: `qr/$line/`?

Comment: Why are you using a regex that's 100,000 characters long?

Comment: what does `I still can print $print` mean?

Comment: @mob $line is still alright, it works with shorter ones already..
@amon so `qr/$line/` will be the same as `$regex`? Sorry to ask this stupid question but i just started working with Perl some hour ago...

Comment: @ysth just my typo, i mean the value of $line is totally fine and readable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl eval does not have such a limit; the following works for me with no error, for instance:

```
my $line = '/' . 'x' x 100000 . '/';
my $regex = eval 'qr' . $line;
print "error: $@\n" if $@;
my $myLength = length($regex);
print "Length of string: $myLength\n";
```

output:

```
Length of string: 100005
```

You have something wrong in your input; examine $@ after the eval to see what.

Comment: I got this 
 Unknown verb pattern '' in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((kim|1)|(a(((()|li)|di)|(((()|li)|di)))))|ram)|bull)|e)|abc)|(111((1(((()|1)|11)|(((()|1)|11))))|((1(((()|1)|11)|(((()|1)|11)))))) at (eval 1) line 1

Why exactly is my regex wrong??

Comment: @Loi.Luu Where in God's name did you find that abomination?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Why do you always ask these non-sense questions?? Anw, I solved the problem already. I got some inappropriate kleen star in my regex. Thank guys :)

Comment: yup, `(*` starts a special control verb (see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs); it's not a valid place for a kleene star.